# How to order the HTTP headers sent by HttpClient or WebRequest?

Tags: c#

Id like to be able to control how the headers are ordered when sending a web request using either HttpClient or WebRequest.

When using HttpClient, Host and Connection are always added at the end, and the other headers are ordered in order that they were added to the Headers collection.

WebRequest adds Host to the end of the headers.

I know that the order of headers does not matter to the webserver, however, id like to order them in a specific way, because the order will be checekd programatically at the server side.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my temporary workaround:

Create a local proxy and pass the HttpClient request through it. Inside the proxy I reorder the headers as I want them.

The local proxy I am using is the Open Source C# [Titanium Web Proxy](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy), which works just fine for the purpose. It supports .NET Standard 2.0, so it is cross platform.

Below are code examples of a test-proxy setup and a client that uses the proxy. You'll have to do your own implementation of the event handlers.

**Client**:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Proxy = new WebProxy($"http://localhost:8000", false),
                UseProxy = true,
            };

            var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler);

            var t  = Task.Run(() => GetDataAsync(client, "http://google.com/"));
            t.Wait();
            var result = t.Result;
        }

        static async Task<string> GetDataAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, string path)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Proxy server setup:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Titanium.Web.Proxy;
using Titanium.Web.Proxy.EventArguments;
using Titanium.Web.Proxy.Models;

namespace ClassLibrary6
{
    public class ProxySetup
    {
        public ProxySetup()
        {
            var proxyServer = new ProxyServer();

            //locally trust root certificate used by this proxy 
            proxyServer.TrustRootCertificate = true;

            //optionally set the Certificate Engine
            //Under Mono only BouncyCastle will be supported
            //proxyServer.CertificateEngine = Network.CertificateEngine.BouncyCastle;

            proxyServer.BeforeRequest += OnRequest;
            proxyServer.BeforeResponse += OnResponse;
            proxyServer.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += OnCertificateValidation;
            proxyServer.ClientCertificateSelectionCallback += OnCertificateSelection;


            var explicitEndPoint = new ExplicitProxyEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8000, true)
            {
                //Exclude HTTPS addresses you don't want to proxy
                //Useful for clients that use certificate pinning
                //for example dropbox.com
                // ExcludedHttpsHostNameRegex = new List<string>() { "google.com", "dropbox.com" }

                //Use self-issued generic certificate on all HTTPS requests
                //Optimizes performance by not creating a certificate for each HTTPS-enabled domain
                //Useful when certificate trust is not required by proxy clients
                // GenericCertificate = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "genericcert.pfx"), "password")
            };

            //An explicit endpoint is where the client knows about the existence of a proxy
            //So client sends request in a proxy friendly manner
            proxyServer.AddEndPoint(explicitEndPoint);
            proxyServer.Start();

            //Transparent endpoint is useful for reverse proxy (client is not aware of the existence of proxy)
            //A transparent endpoint usually requires a network router port forwarding HTTP(S) packets or DNS
            //to send data to this endPoint
            var transparentEndPoint = new TransparentProxyEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8001, true)
            {
                //Generic Certificate hostname to use
                //when SNI is disabled by client
                GenericCertificateName = "google.com"
            };

            proxyServer.AddEndPoint(transparentEndPoint);

            //proxyServer.UpStreamHttpProxy = new ExternalProxy() { HostName = "localhost", Port = 8888 };
            //proxyServer.UpStreamHttpsProxy = new ExternalProxy() { HostName = "localhost", Port = 8888 };

            foreach (var endPoint in proxyServer.ProxyEndPoints)
                Console.WriteLine("Listening on '{0}' endpoint at Ip {1} and port: {2} ",
                    endPoint.GetType().Name, endPoint.IpAddress, endPoint.Port);

            //Only explicit proxies can be set as system proxy!
            //proxyServer.SetAsSystemHttpProxy(explicitEndPoint);
            //proxyServer.SetAsSystemHttpsProxy(explicitEndPoint);

            //wait here (You can use something else as a wait function, I am using this as a demo)
            Console.Read();

            //Unsubscribe & Quit
            proxyServer.BeforeRequest -= OnRequest;
            proxyServer.BeforeResponse -= OnResponse;
            proxyServer.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= OnCertificateValidation;
            proxyServer.ClientCertificateSelectionCallback -= OnCertificateSelection;

            proxyServer.Stop();
        }

        public async Task OnRequest(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
        {
            e.WebSession.Request.RequestHeaders.AddHeader("Ab", "Moo");

            var headers = e.WebSession.Request.RequestHeaders.GetAllHeaders();

            var ordered = headers.OrderBy(x => x.Name);

            e.WebSession.Request.RequestHeaders.Clear();

            foreach (var httpHeader in ordered)
            {
                e.WebSession.Request.RequestHeaders.AddHeader(httpHeader);
            }

        }

        public async Task OnResponse(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public Task OnCertificateValidation(object sender, CertificateValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public Task OnCertificateSelection(object sender, CertificateSelectionEventArgs e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```