# How to place HttpWebRequest Host header first?

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I'm using standard HttpWebRequest to get html page:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace TestConsole.Classes {
    class RequestHeadersOrder {
        public void Test() {
            var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com");
            req.Proxy = new WebProxy("localhost", 8888); // for debug in Fiddler proxy (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
            req.Host = "www.google.com";
            req.UserAgent = "Robot-tester";
            req.Accept = "*/*";
            req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US");
            req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
            req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            string html;
            using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
            using (var respStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                respStream.CopyTo(ms);
                html = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
            Console.WriteLine(html);
        }
    }
}
```

This produces request headers (raw format):

```
GET https://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Robot-tester
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.google.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

But most browsers use different headers order: "Host" header first, then "User agent", then other headers. So, I need this:

```
GET https://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: Robot-tester
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Please advice me how to place "Host" header first. This is important for some web sites.

Comment: You don't. .NET does this for you.

Comment: Just tested this code in .NET Core - all is ok, header "Host" placed first, then "User-agent". So, this affects only .NET Framework (4.7). But unfortunately I can't switch to .NET Core now.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507944/how-to-order-the-http-headers-sent-by-httpclient-or-webrequest

Comment: @AndrewKotov This looks very interesting, thank you for advice. I will try that if I won't find simpler solution.